# Couldn't connect to Redis server in the simple Spring Boot web app RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, redis

I just start to learn Docker and Redis. I have s simple Spring Boot web application and it works locally good. But when I try to use "docker compose up --build" and go to localhost:8080/count page it throws an Exception `"Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis] with root cause"`
How to solve this issue?

**Configuration**

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory();
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
public class Controller {
    private static final String VISITS_KEY = "visits";
    private RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public Controller(RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate) {
        this.redisTemplate = redisTemplate;
    }

    @GetMapping("/count")
    public String getVisits() {
        Long visits = incrementVisits();
        return "Number of visits is " + visits;
    }

    private Long incrementVisits() {
        return redisTemplate.opsForValue().increment(VISITS_KEY);
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String welcomePage(@RequestParam("name") Optional<String> name) {
        if (name.isEmpty())
            return "Hey there!";
        else return "Hey " + name.get() + "!";
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.data.redis.host=redis-server
spring.data.redis.port=6379
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis-server:
    image: 'redis'
  testjava-app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

**dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:22

WORKDIR /app
COPY .mvn/ .mvn
COPY mvnw pom.xml ./
RUN ./mvnw dependency:resolve
COPY src ./src

CMD ["./mvnw", "spring-boot:run"]
```

**Fool Error:**

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis] with root cause
testdockerwebapp-testjava-app-1  | 
testdockerwebapp-testjava-app-1  | java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
testdockerwebapp-testjava-app-1  |  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
testdockerwebapp-testjava-app-1  |  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:682) ~[na:na]
testdockerwebapp-testjava-app-1  |  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:1060) ~[na:na]
testdockerwebapp-testjava-app-1  |  at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:337) ~[netty-transport-4.1.100.Final.jar:4.1.100.Final]
testdockerwebapp-testjava-app-1  |  at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334) ~[netty-transport-4.1.100.Final.jar:4.1.100.Final]
testdockerwebapp-testjava-app-1  |  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.100.Final.jar:4.1.100.Final]
testdockerwebapp-testjava-app-1  |  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[netty-transport-4.1.100.Final.jar:4.1.100.Final]
testdockerwebapp-testjava-app-1  |  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.100.Final.jar:4.1.100.Final]
testdockerwebapp-testjava-app-1  |  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.100.Final.jar:4.1.100.Final]
testdockerwebapp-testjava-app-1  |  at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.100.Final.jar:4.1.100.Final]
testdockerwebapp-testjava-app-1  |  at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.100.Final.jar:4.1.100.Final]
testdockerwebapp-testjava-app-1  |  at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.100.Final.jar:4.1.100.Final]
testdockerwebapp-testjava-app-1  |  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570) ~[na:na]
```

Locally when I go to this page(localhost:8080/count) it counts the number of visits to this page and show it